# how select signed in chrome browser android studio emulator for flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

run flutter project in chrome emulator but it will open in new instance of chrome browser i have already 5 account sign in so i want that any one of them use for run emulator

```
i tried to copy url and pest on new sign chrome windows it work but on that windows it doesn't auto reload when make changes on project
```